# How to count future time delta when parameter is only hour and minute? Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone


time = input('Insert time: ')
f = '%H:%M'
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime(f)
diff = (datetime.strptime(time, f) - datetime.strptime(now, f)).total_seconds()
print(f'{diff} seconds')
print(f'{diff / 60 / 60} hours')
```

If the current time is 7:00 and I want a countdown for 2:00 the next day, it gives a negative time delta because it calculates it for the current day.

```
Expected output is: 18 hours
Reality: -6 hours
```

Any ideas on what's the best way to implement this? I don't want the user to input dates, just hour:minute.

Edit: Time format is 24 hours and only Hour:Minute (i.e 07:00, 18:30)
Objective is to avoid a negative time delta when the current time is 07:00 (7AM, today) and you enter 02:00 (2AM, the next day). The code is counting it 02:00 (2AM, the same day).

Comment: Could you specify what is your hour format, like 24-hours format and also, clarify your objective in the question. As from this, it is difficult to understand what your goal is.

Comment: So, you want to interpret the user input as *the next HH:MM in the future*? E.g. if it's 12 noon, "7:00" means 7 am the next day, but "19:00" means 7 pm the same day?

Comment: I added some more example. I'm sorry for not being more clearer, I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: @deceze exactly! If it's 12 noon and I enter 7:00 it will give a negative time delta of (-5 hours). It's supposed to be 19 hours!

Comment: @Nick You are right! It's for a game that uses UTC as a time reference, so DST never crossed my mind and your equation works perfect. Although it's probably still best practice to consider DST which I will do from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

value = input('Insert time:')
t = time(*map(int, value.split(':')))
target = datetime.combine(date.today(), t)
now = datetime.now()

if target < now:
    target += timedelta(days=1)

print(target - now)
```

Create a complete `datetime` timestamp by combining the input time with today's date. If that's before *now*, add a day to it.